# Close Lightbox dialog when user click on back button

Tags: dialog, modal-dialog, lightbox, simplemodal, lightbox2

How to close lightbox dialog when user clicks on back button. I know it's possible if URL hash changes, therefor is there any way to change url hash if user clicks on Lightbox items?

I've checked Lightbox options and I didn't find the specific option to do that.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Try Fancybox - https://fancyapps.com/ - it works as you described.